Two-out of three property for covering maps on quotient spaces
If we have covering maps $p_H \colon X \to X/H$ and
$p_G \to X/G$ where $G$ acts properly discontinuously on $X$ and $H \leq G$, I want to show that the map $X/H \to X/G$ is a covering map.
Could someone help or give a reference for this?

Doesn't $G$ act properly discontinuously on $X/H$, making the map $X/H \rightarrow X/G$ the quotient map determined by this action? Another approach: locally, the map $X/H \rightarrow X/G$ is given by composing a local inverse of $p_H$ with $p_G$. This tells us $X/H \rightarrow X/G$ is a local homeomorphism, so now you just need to argue that $X/G$ is evenly covered by this map.

To the first part, yes, but I'm not sure how to conclude from that that the map is a covering map. For the other part, I think I understand what you're saying, but not sure how to argue it.

The way you posed your question makes me think you already know that the quotient map determined by a properly discontinuous group action is a covering map. So if you understand my first sentence, you should be able to conclude from there :)

The problem is: what is the group that now acts properly discontinuously on $X/H$? $G$ would not since for example the identity and any $h \in H$ fixes all points. It should be $G/H$, but we do not know that $H$ is normal in $G$. So I don't believe we can use this here.

I'm not sure whether my solution is correct, but I came up with the following:
We know that $p_H$ and $p_G$ are
local homeomorphisms. Suppose
$V \subset X$ is open such that
$gV \cap V = \varnothing$ for all $g \neq e$.
Then $p_H|_{gV} \colon gV \to 
    p_H(gV)$ is a homeomorphism, so if
$U = p_H(gV)$, then
$p'|_{U} = p_G|_{gV} p_H|_{gV}^{-1} \colon
    U \to p_G(gV)$ is a homeomorphism. Hence
$p'$ is a local homeomorphism.
But also,
$p'^{-1}(p_G(V)) =
    \bigcup_{gH \text{ cosets}} p_H(gV) $. Here
we need only take the union on the cosets since $p_H(gV) \cap p_H(g'V)$ if and only if $g'H. V \cap gH.V \neq \varnothing$ if and only if
$g^{-1}g' \in H$. So
in particular, this is a disjoint union
of sets of the form above, so
$p'$ restricts to a homeomorphism on each of them.
If someone could let me know whether it looks right, that would be great!
How does one rigorously argue that $p_H|_{gV} \colon gV \to p_H(gV)$ is a homeomorphism?

The last line of your proof could use a bit more elaboration, since it's the key to the proof. (Everything prior looks right, and is just an expansion of what JMM notes in his comment, namely that we compose a section of $p_H$ with $p_G$ to get a local homeo)

Thank you. I've added a line on that, but I also still feel a bit uncertain of precisely why $p_H|{gV}$ is a homeomorphism. Could you shed some light on it maybe?
Edit: could one say that $p_H|{gV}$ must be injective? I believe it is open and continuous, hence it would indeed be an embedding. I suppose injectivity also follows from $G \leq H$. Let me know if that seems right, thank you! :)
